# Python tkinter quiz how to change questions

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a quiz with tkinter and I have made the first question and its works fine but i am having trouble changing it to another question. I have tried using variables to check if the first question has been answered but it did not work. My question is how to add more questions too the quiz
My code:

```
import time
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
TestLabel = Label(root, text = "What is the capital of Maryland")
Turn = 0

TestLabel.pack()
if Turn == 1:
    TestLabel.config(text = "What is the capital of Delaware?")
    print("1")
global scoreA

scoreA = 0
RightOne = Label(text = f"Great job!, You have a score of {scoreA}")
def Remove_Output():
    RightOne.pack_forget()
e.pack()
def Click():
    global scoreA
    if e.get() == "Annapolis":
        scoreA = scoreA + 1
        RightOne.config(text = f"Great job! You have a score of {scoreA}")
        RightOne.pack()
        root.after(2000, Remove_Output)
        
        
    else:
        
        RightOne.config(text = f"Thats not it, you have a score of {scoreA}")
        RightOne.pack()
        root.after(2000, Remove_Output)

    
        
        


root.geometry("500x500")
ButtonA = Button(root, text = "Enter", command = Click)
ButtonA.pack()






root.mainloop()
``
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible method would be to store your questions and answers in a list (or dictionary) and then bring in a question/answer pair to ask.  Following is a proof of principle version of your code with a simple two-question list.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

# In lieu of a hard coded list, one could read in questions and answers from a text file and build a list that way.

questions = ["What is the capital of Maryland", "What is the highest mountain in the world"]
answers   = ["Annapolis", "Mt. Everest"]


scoreA = 0
num = 0

root = tk.Tk()
e = tk.Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
TestLabel = tk.Label(root, text = questions[num])
Turn = True

if Turn:
    TestLabel.config(text = questions[num])
    TestLabel.pack()
    
RightOne = tk.Label(text = f"Great job!, You have a score of {scoreA}")
    
def Remove_Output():
    RightOne.pack_forget()
e.pack()
def Click():
    global scoreA
    global num
    if e.get() == answers[num]:
        scoreA = scoreA + 1
        RightOne.config(text = f"Great job! You have a score of {scoreA}")
        RightOne.pack()
        root.after(2000, Remove_Output)
        num = num + 1
        if num == len(questions):
            Turn = False
            return
        TestLabel.config(text = questions[num])
        TestLabel.pack()
        e.delete(0, 30)
        
    else:
        
        RightOne.config(text = f"Thats not it, you have a score of {scoreA}")
        RightOne.pack()
        root.after(2000, Remove_Output)
        
root.geometry("500x500")
ButtonA = tk.Button(root, text = "Enter", command = Click)
ButtonA.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

One could definitely get more sophisticated with building a list of questions (e.g. read in the list of questions and answers from a file) so as to keep the game fresh.

Give that a try.

Additional notes:

Per your comment below about moving on from a wrong answer, I tested out your code and did some further revisions and code tweaks to try and compact the code as much as possible but still address your request and make the program a bit more robust.  Following is the refactored code snippet.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

questions = ["What is the capital of Maryland", "What is the highest mountain in the world", "Who am I"]
answers   = ["Annapolis", "Mt. Everest", "Player"]

scoreA    = 0
num       = 0

root = tk.Tk()

RightOne  = tk.Label(text = f"")
TestLabel = tk.Label(root, text = questions[num])
TestLabel.pack()   
e = tk.Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
e.pack()
    
def Remove_Output():
    RightOne.pack_forget()
    if num >= len(questions):
        RightOne.config(text = f"Your final score is {scoreA}")
        RightOne.pack()
    
def Click():
    global scoreA
    global num
    if num>= len(questions):    # Avoid index overflow
        return
    if e.get() == answers[num]:
        scoreA += 1
        RightOne.config(text = f"Great job! You have a score of {scoreA}")
    else:
        RightOne.config(text = f"Thats not it, you have a score of {scoreA}")
        
    RightOne.pack()
    root.after(2000, Remove_Output)
    e.delete(0, 30)    
    num += 1
    
    if num < len(questions):
        TestLabel.config(text = questions[num])
        TestLabel.pack()

root.geometry("500x500")
ButtonA = tk.Button(root, text = "Enter", command = Click)
ButtonA.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This version will move on from an incorrect answer, plus display a final score once all questions have been processed.  Give that a try.  I am sure that you can embellish this to make it into a nice quiz game.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help however is there a way for it to move on when you get it wrong?

Comment: Per your request, I added in a more robust version of the code staying true to the spirit of your game.

Comment: Thank you for all the help! I shall get back to you when this becomes something